# Directory directive: AuthType None but still need an AuthProvider?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, authentication

**I'm using Apache 2.2 instead of 2.4, which explains the error in the title. After Brain99 posted his comment, I found out that I had 2.2, adjusted my configuration to what he suggested (which still didn't work), tried around a bit, slept a night and the next day I found out, that I forgot the Include statements for the mod-enabled directory!**

For now I just need the server to let me download files from one specific folder (in my case I chose /opt/myFolder for that task)

Distribution is Debian 6.0

*edit_start*

<strike>Apache version is 2.4, according to their official documentation, the Order/Allow clauses are deprecated and should not be used anymore</strike>

I'm an idiot: Apache version is 2.2.

*edit_end*

<strike>My directory directives in apache2.conf look like this:</strike>

```
<IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</IfModule>
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
DocumentRoot "/opt/myFolder"
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denie
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/myFolder/*">
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        AuthType None
        Require all allow
</Directory>
```

When I try to access a file inside that folder (http://myserver.de/aTestFile.zip) I get an Internal Server Error. Also Apache writes the following error into it's log:

```
configuration error:  couldn't check user.  Check your authn provider!: /aTestFile.zip
```

Why would I need an authn provider if I don't want any authentication? Also I hope someone can explain to me what kind of AuthenticationProvider I'd need for that. Everytime I search for those things I get pointed at people asking how to protect files/directories with passwords or restrict access to some IP addresses, which doesn't really help me.

ok, since I've Apache version 2.2, here is the error I get when using the Order/Deny/Allow commands instead of AuthType/Require:

```
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is due to the following erroneous configuration directives:

```
Require all denie
Require all allow
```

Try the following configuration instead:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/opt/myFolder/*">
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        AuthType None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Edit 2**: Your problem could also be due to the [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) module not being loaded. You can try enabling this with `a2enmod authz_host` and restarting apache.

Also, it seems that `AuthType None` is invalid. Just remove the `AuthType` directive entirely from your configuration.

Comment: well, in that case Apache doesn't start at all. Output from apachectl start `Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. Are you sure that this option is still available in Apache 2.4? I saw a few forum threads where it was said that those options were dropped and replaced by the Require clauses.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I'm stupid. My apache version *is* 2.2. But why do I get that error?

Comment: also, even with your edits it doesn't work.

Comment: to your 2nd edit: AuthType None is supported, according to official documentation. Anyway, when I remove it, apache says that it `couldn't perform authentication. AuthType is not set.`

Comment: Are we looking at the same docs? According to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#authtype), the accepted values are `Basic` and `Digest`. The value `None` is apache 2.3+ only.

Comment: yes, I looked at the 2.4 docs, sorry.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add (back) in the configuration you are currently using? With all version mixups and changes that'll make it easier to see what might still be wrong.

Comment: well, I got it working with the appropiate config for 2.2 (Order/allow combination). I made the following mistakes:

I thought I had Apache 2.4, which wasn't the case and I found out about that after your answer

I tried your config, which didn't work at first and gave me the `Invalid command`error. After a night of sleep, I looked at the apache config again and saw that stupid me forgot to add the include directives for the module-enabled directory.

Comment: could you explain how to include these modules? thanks